# Shape positioning in categorical grouped bar chart

Tags: plotly, bar-chart, positioning

How can I put the shape in the categorical bar chart below in the middle of the bar specifying the number of giraffes in the SF Zoo (as shown in magenta in the attached picture)?

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
animals=['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys']

fig = go.Figure(data=[
    go.Bar(name='SF Zoo', x=animals, y=[20, 14, 23]),
    go.Bar(name='LA Zoo', x=animals, y=[12, 18, 29])
])

# Change the bar mode
fig.update_layout(barmode='group')

# Shape
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=['giraffes', 'giraffes', 'orangutans', 'orangutans'],
                         y=[21, 25, 25, 16],
                         fill=None, mode="lines", line=dict(color='rgba(0,0,0,1)',width=2),
                         showlegend=False
                        )
             )

    
fig.show()
```

[image: picture of output]

Comment: I don't think that's possible without some kind of hacky/fragile solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Maximilian Peters pointed out, there isn't a good way of referencing a point an arbitrary amount between *categorical coordinates*.

The best you can do is set the `xref` to `paper` meaning that the x-axis is scaled to be between 0 and 1. Then you have to guess and check where the x-coordinates should be to line up where you want them. Since your y-axis is numerical, you can reference the y-values you like directly. After some trial and error, drawing lines between (0.10, 20), (0,10, 25), (0.44, 25), (0.44, 14) gets you pretty close to your desired annotation.

This is definitely hacky, and not generalizable if you add more bars, or change the width of the bars in any way.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
animals=['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys']

fig = go.Figure(data=[
    go.Bar(name='SF Zoo', x=animals, y=[20, 14, 23]),
    go.Bar(name='LA Zoo', x=animals, y=[12, 18, 29])
])

# Change the bar mode
fig.update_layout(barmode='group')

# Shape composed of three lines, looping through coordinates
x_coords = [0.10, 0.10, 0.44, 0.44]
y_coords = [20, 25, 25, 14]
for i in range(1,len(x_coords)):
    fig.add_shape(
        type="line",
        xref="paper",
        x0=x_coords[i-1], 
        y0=y_coords[i-1], 
        x1=x_coords[i], 
        y1=y_coords[i],
        line=dict(color="magenta",width=3)
    )
    
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @Derek O. I figured that I could use absolute positioning via `xref="paper", yref="paper"` and thus draw 3 lines separately, however, the for loop appears more elegant (all new to this). I hope that the plotly developers provide a better solution for this issue and statistical annotation in particular to categorical data in the future. I need to do a 2-way ANOVA and add p-values to a similar graph, but I have not found a way that is convenient to do so in Plotly yet?

Comment: @hans yeah Plotly is a cool library and the interactive plots are great, but they come at the cost of tunability. There are definitely more features relating to categorical bar charts that need to be added, and I wouldn't be surprised if there's an open issue for this exact problem. If your question regarding adding p-values to your bar chart is different from this question, feel free to post a new question so that me or someone else can help you out with that!